# Extract substring from find result

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I need to get the interface indentification number of a VPN connection.
So I use that command:

```
route print 256.* | find "The VPN Name"
```

This displays a line like that:

```
 46..................The VPN Name
```

But I only want the digits at the begining. The number can be 1 to 3 digits long. How can I do that?

------------EDIT-----------

Partial solution:

```
for /f %%i in ('route print 256.* ^| find "The VPN Name"') do set GC_Line=%%i
echo %GC_Line:~0,3%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just split by `.` and space and take the first token:

```
for /f "delims=. " %%i in ('route print 256.* ^| find "The VPN Name"') do set GC_Line=%%i
```

Comment: You were very close. You already stripped the first space(s) by the default delimiter `SPACE`. The only thing to change was to add another delimiter (`.`)

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex like this one :
\d+(?=.)

Comment: I thought to extract the characters 1 to 3 and then delete the points at the end. Whether I choose this solution or yours, I would first have to know how to redirect the output of the find command to do it. Maybe by saving the result in a variable, but here I do not know how. I do not want to go through a temporary file.

Comment: Windows, it's in the tags list. I found how to get the first 3 characters, but I still need to trim the ending dots.

Comment: find and/or findstr always returns every full line that contains a match, it is not capable of returning "match" or sub-strings only

I think you will have to use PowerShell

Comment: With the CLI I could use %str:.=% but it doesn't work with batch files.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try (Powershell)

```
$string = route print 256.*
$regex_vpn= [regex] '.*The VPN Name'
$regex_no= [regex] '\d+(?=.)'

$match_vpn = $regex_vpn.Match($string)
$match_no = $regex_no.Match($match_vpn.Value)
$match_no.Value
```